# Does AWS greengrass fully support C++ as it does python

Tags: python, c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If one goes AWS console to create a Lambda function the required runtime selection only lists C#, Go, Java8, and Python so why No C++ here?

Then in AWS information I have read like "only C++ and python SDKs provide AWS greengrass specific functionality for Discovery Service, and CA downloads.

I know C++ I do not know Python, and C/C++ is the universal language for embedded devices (as a rule) so I would prefer to stick with C++ with AWS unless AWS folk are not fully supporting C++ and or heading to python instead.

So the question is Does AWS greengrass fully support C++ as it does python? I do not have the AWS developer support level so I can not ask the technical support at AWS,

Comment: No-one outside of AWS can answer your question on whether or not Lambda will one day support C++ (and AWS won't answer it either, until it's announced). I would encourage you to move forward with whichever supported language works best for you (and I would recommend Python, personally). If Lambda supports C++ in the future then you can come back and rewrite your code in C++ if you like, but I suspect that you will not want to do that.

Comment: I am a newbie to things AWS so I am trying to realize the best development framework that particularly fits AWS IOT Greengrass development and also catches MEAN development with AWS,  How many languages must I know and use?  What languages can only do?  AWS lists many SDKs for most the popular languages but what our the differences in capability being these offerings, hard to know because Amazon folk do not give a spreadsheet or such to show you.

Comment: FYI Seems maybe the best heads up on greengrass https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/.  I further ask are there any significant benefits to using C++ in AWS over python?  C++ produces faster and smaller code as a rule but perhaps that is not needed anywhere in AWS IOT or is it?

Comment: C and C++ are critically important on small devices (IoT), but not the best-supported server-side, and certainly not the most productive. AWS non-device SDKs should be largely the same in terms of service coverage though I suspect Java and Python lead in that regard.

Comment: You can call a C++ exe from inside a Nodejs Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish two thing:

- **Lambda function** is a Function as a Service for **Serverless Computing** in AWS and at this time supports Node.js, Python, Java, C# , Go. The main idea of Greengrass is to bring some cloud capabilities (like Databases, lambda function and other services) near to IoT devices in order to reduce the latency. More likely, Greengrass will be used for **Fog Comuting**. It also provides MQTT broker in order to enable IoT devices to communicate with each other in local network.
- **AWS IoT SDKs** are something different than Lambda functions. With help of AWS IoT SDKs you can connect your devices to the AWS IoT broker or configure AWS IoT service in cloud (obviously, you should have proper credentials). These SDKs are written in different programming languages for different devices which at this time are Embedded C, JavaScript, Arduino Yún, Java, Python, iOS, Android and C++ SDK.

As mentioned in AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html), some functionalities like Greengrass discovery are only supported in C++ and Python. It is related to AWS IoT SDK for discovering the IoT device on the Greengrass network in order to allow IoT devices to be able to communicate with each other in Greengrass network. When the devices run Greengrass discovery function, it will return some information about Greengrass group along with CA Certificate of the Greengrass group.

Answer (score 0):

you can create lambda function in any language. I don't have idea about greengrass but you can go through the official documentation here. The best source for AWS related query is their own documentation. [C++ AWS Lambda functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)